# VLC Videoplayer in C# Windows Form doesn't play .flv web file

Tags: c#, vlc, flv

I'm using a xml file which put out a link to a .flv file.

Now I want to play this file in a VLC Videoplayerscreen in my C# Windows form.
When I place the link direct in the VLC player's MRL, it works fine and plays the file.
When I place the string with the .flv link in the code inside the MRL, it doesn't play.

What I have:

```
try
        {
            // XML works fine and flv link is placed inside nuvid
            XmlNodeList nuvid = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("location");
            vlcvid.MRL = nuvid[1].InnerText;// placing the link inside the MRL
            vlcvid.AutoPlay = true; // Try to play
            MessageBox.Show(vlcvid.MRL);// the link is placed succesfull inside the MRL

        }

catch   { 

        }
```

Comment: Where is the flv file stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I add the video link to a playlist and start playing the playlist. It works!

```
vlcvid.playlist.add(vlcvid.MRL);
vlcvid.playlist.next();
```